# SetFocus causing Run time error

Tags: vb5

I am getting:
**Run-time error '5':**
**Invalid procedure call or argument**

this seems to happen when Text(1).SetFocus is called.

However, I dont see this run time error for all the cases where I have used SetFocus. Just 2-3 places it is causing this error.

```
Text(1).SelStart = 3
Text(1).SelLength = 1
Text(1).SetFocus
```

I tried:

```
Text(1).Enabled = True  
Text(1).Visible = True
```

just above .SelStart, but it didn't fix the issue.

UPDATE:

If I run the application using debugger/VB5 IDE, then i dont see any error. But when I create the exe and run then I see this error.

UPDATE:
Even though I was doing
    Text(1).Enabled = True
    Text(1).Visible = True
it didnt work, but when I did

```
If Text(1).Enabled And Text(1).Visible Then  
    Text(1).SetFocus
End If
```

It  didnt show run time error. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Oh dear .. VB5 really? Please say that is a typo :(

Comment: Yeah it is VB5, unfortunately.

Comment: Where is the code located - what is the larger context? There might be issues if SetFocus is called during a "loading" event or before the control/container is visible, IIRC. It's been forever.

Comment: I am a newbie to VB. What I can see in the call stack is that this is been called by Project.Form1.Function

Comment: Hah! I don't remember that stuff :(